# SpriteKit addChild order is different after removing items and readding

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, sprite

I have 3 `SkSpriteNodes`: A `man` a `background` and a `groundType`. These are all pngs and sit ontop of each other to create a scene. I add them using `addChild` by adding the `background` then the `groundType` and then the `man`.  This works fine. When the user gets to the end of the screen I erase all except the man and change the `background` and the `groundType`.  Similar to the way Pitfall works. When I remove them and add them back in they appear in wrong order. I call `cleanScreen()` then `loadBackground()` then `loadLevelType()`.  Which you would think would add the background then the level type. What I see instead is leveltype below then background, so you can't see the level type. Even if I switch the order of the functions this still happens.  I cannot seems to find anywhere that gives me information on how the ordering of sprites work when removed and added back in. It seems inconsistent. I have thoroughly read the docs for Obj-C and I also tried using `insertChild:atIndex` but that did not seem to work for me either.

```
...
cleanScreen()
loadBackground()
loadLevelType()
...
func cleanScreen() {
    levelType.removeFromParent()
    bg.removeFromParent()
} 

func loadBackground() {
    var bgNum = currentLevelData["bg"]! as String // resolves to "2"
    bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg_\(bgNum)")
    bg.name = "bg"
    scene.addChild(bg)
}

func loadLevelType() {
    var levelTypeInfo = currentLevelData["type"]! as String // resolves to "lake"
    levelType = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: levelTypeInfo)
    println(levelTypeInfo)
    levelType.name = "level_type"
    levelType.position.y = -140
    scene.addChild(levelType)
}
```

When I loop over `scene.children` the object are in the correct order. I have never played around with `zPosition` before. The names come back as:

```
man   
bg
level_type
```

But they appear on screen as `man` `level_type` `bg`. I added opacity to the background and I see now for sure that they are not being rendered in the correct order now that I can see through the background.

Comment: enumerate over scene.children array and log their names - are they in the correct order? If not, the problem is clear. If yes, perhaps you change zPosition somewhere or forget to properly remove or add a node.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D They are in the correct order! That is very interesting. I have never played with zPosition. When I log their zPosition on looping through they are all 0.0

Comment: weird, might be a bug. In any case you can work around that by setting the zPosition for each node.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Does seems like a bug. I'll try setting the zPosition.

Comment: I think it is a bug. I reported it on the forums.

Comment: In your SKView, did you set ignoresSiblingOrder to true?  If so, the child order has no effect on what goes on top of what.